# How do I replace bolts for my toilet that were concreted into the original flange?

Tags: bathroom, toilet, bolts, flange

This is a pic of one of the bolts. But I don't see a channel for it to turn/slip out of. The toilet I bought needs longer bolts.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have access from below it really is a quick job to put a new flange on.  But honestly if the one you have is that solid and has worked well (doesn't clog a lot), then I would simply just throw on a bolt extender.

[image]

Note:  Your bolt looks like it extends pretty far so not sure what toilet needs more than that but gave you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to snap the bolt off, or if it will unscrew, if it is rusted or corroded, and use a lag type anchor with standard threads on top. However, for the wax ring to seal properly, Id say best bet is a new flange. You can get retrofit flanges that bolt down over what you have, basically creating a new flange like if yours broke, or the floor was raised by tile etc.

Like any of these items:
http://www.homedepot.com/p/DANCO-HydroSeat-Toilet-Flange-Repair-10672X/204403879

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Superior-Tool-SuperRing-Closet-Replacement-Ring-21015/202538331